# Code Not Getting Invoked After Loop Statement

Tags: java, jsf

In my jsf page I am calling a method called saveinsert and in my saveInsert method I have the following code.

```
try {
    System.out.println("rchd 1");
    for (Employees items : editCellItems) {
        System.out.println("rchd 2");
        items.setEmpId(empBean.getEmployeesId());
        System.out.println("after assigning  "+items.getEmployeesId());

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("exception "+e.getMessage());  
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

where editCellItems is declared like

```
List<Employees> editCellItems= new ArrayList<Employees>();
```

and empBean is declared like this

```
Employees empBean= new Employees();
```

My problem is when I run my jsf page rchd 2 and code after that is not getting invoked.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Do you ever add any objects to editCellItems?

Comment: `editCellItems` is empty.  Nothing is getting insterted into it.

Comment: I am assuming you have a catch block, do you print the exception?  (Please post the rest of your code)

Comment: No objects is added to editCellItems. idea behind is I am trying to do an insert to database. is it because editCellItems is null? If so how could I use editCellItems to pass to my method for data insertion?

Comment: wait, your looping through a null list??

Comment: if I am looping through a null list, how can I make sure to add values to editCellItems before the loop and then iterate?

Comment: @Polappan the thing is you can loop thought a null list, and from your code it is not null, its just empty. You have to fill it. e.g. `editCellItems.add(empBean);`

Comment: @RMT `editCellItems.add(empBean);` did the trick. What I am trying to do is the best approach?

Comment: @Polappan I don't know what you are planning to do with the List or how many elements you have so it's hard to judge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you add values into `editCellItems` using the `List<?>` `add()` meothod. Also When doing a for each loop make sure you do not add or remove items or you will get an `Exception`.
e.g.:

```
editCellItems.add(empBean);
```

edit: Also If you only have 1 element in your `editCellItems`, you might not want to use a list unless you are adding more,

Comment: ok thanks. Make sure you add values into `editCellItems` using the `List<?> add()` meothod. For this could give an example?

Comment: The example I gave, is exactly what you will need. and you can add more employees if you need to. If you add empBean like that, you don't have to iterate through the loop to set the empID since it will be that item already.

Comment: thanks, I have more elements in Employees table and hence I thought I would list. Appreciated.

Comment: The only reason it's not getting executed is because there is nothing in the loop(If it was null, you'd get an exception). Make sure something is populated in the Array.

Answer (score 0):

If no objects are in editCellItems, then it will iterate through the for loop 0 times. Therefore, you need to add some objects first:

```
editCellItems.add(empBean);
```